# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double ToDouble(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, linq

I am currently converting a stored procedure from an old system by some old programmers into a linq but I can't figure out what is causing this error. The code is as follows:

**Controller:**

```
var ObligationRequestDetailsTotalCostByOoe = (from p in db.iBudget_ObligationRequestDetails
where p.ooe_general_id != null && p.is_approved == 1
group p by p.ooe_general_id into g
select new
{
id = g.Key,
amount = g.Sum(p => Convert.ToDouble(p.amount))
}).ToList();
```

**Model:**

```
public int id { get; set; }
public string amount { get; set; }
```

I tried to change **Convert.ToDouble()** to **Double.Parse()** but this error *'Single Parse(System.String)'* showed. 
I tried to add **'System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture'** after the *p.amount* but still the error persist.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: EF is trying to convert expression to SQL and there is no equivalent.

Comment: @Nkosi what turn around can I do here? I tried to do the tips here = https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/exception-linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-tostring but failed miserably

Comment: @mjwills p.amount is a value from the model iBudget_ObligationRequestDetails which is as listed above, a string variable

Comment: Split the query up before the grouping, use `AsEnumerable` and then you should be able to use the convert or parse method after

Comment: Why is it a string type if it is an amount? Is it possible to change the DB (and the C#) to be a different data type?

Comment: @Nkosi Where should I add the AsEnumerable? I tried doing your suggestion earlier which looked like this  amount = g.AsEnumerable().Sum(p => float.Parse(p.amount)) but error still showing

Comment: @mjwills I don't know. The previous developers had this in their codes. The bad thing is that it has foreign keys so I can't change the datatype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use `AsEnumerable` so as to work with the records in memory after it has been returned from the database. Then you will be able to use `Convert.ToDouble`

```
var ObligationRequestDetailsTotalCostByOoe = (from p in db.iBudget_ObligationRequestDetails
where p.ooe_general_id != null && p.is_approved == 1
group p by p.ooe_general_id into g
select g) // <-- db call
.AsEnumerable() //<-- memory call
.Select(g => new {
    id = g.Key,
    amount = g.Sum(p => Convert.ToDouble(p.amount))
})
.ToList();
```

Comment: Ohhh. It worked! Thanks for this. So I was doing the .AsEnumerable() wrong